# How do I find the solutions of this equation?

Tags: trigonometry

> How do I find the solutions of this equation: 
>  $$\tan^2 (x)=-1$$

Answer (score 6):

There is no solution since any real number squared is always positive.

Answer (score 4):

*(Edited after Julian's comment)*

There might be complex solutions. In order to find these write

$$\tan z={1\over i}{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}\over e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}={1\over i}{u-1\over u+1}$$

with $u:=e^{2iz}$. With these conventions we have to solve the equation

$$-\left({u-1\over u+1}\right)^2=-1\ ,\quad{\rm i.e.}\quad {u-1\over u+1}=\pm 1\ .$$

As $(u-1)/(u+1)$ cannot be $1$ the last equation has the single  solution $u=0$, so that we now have to determine the solutions $z\in{\mathbb C}$ of the equation

$$e^{2iz}\ = 0\ ;$$

but there is no such $z$.

Comment: There is a $1/i$ missing in the formula for $\tan z$. This makes a great difference, since there are no solutions, real or complex. This can be seen from Chandrasekhar's answer, since $\sec x=0$ has no solution, real or complex.

Comment: @Julian Aguirre: How could I!

Comment: Thank you for your responses! could you help me in solving this following equation too,$$tanx=2x/(1-x^2 )$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$ \tan^{2}(x) = -1 \Rightarrow 1 + \tan^{2}(x) = 0 \Rightarrow \sec^{2}(x) = 0.$$

Oh, on the other hand note that $x^{2} = -1$ has no real solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\tan^2(0) = 0$ and for any other $x \neq 0$, $\tan^2(x) > 0$.

If you plot $\tan^2(x)$ and $-1$ you will see that those 2 curves never intersect, because $\tan^2(x) \geq 0$, $x\in{\mathbb R}$.

[image]

Therefore there are no real solutions.